# Linking patients and diagnosis in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two tables, Patients & Diagnosis. So far, I've managed to insert/display data from database into patients card, and their diagnosis. Pretty easy.

To display the data for both tables (patients and diagnosis) I use:

```
    $sql = "SELECT id, datetime, patientname  FROM patients ORDER BY datetime DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

To insert the data, I use:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnadd'])){
$sql = "INSERT INTO patients (id, datetime, patientname)
    values('".$_POST['id']."','".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."','".$_POST['patientname']."')
";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    header('Location: patientadded.php');
} else {
    echo "Error " .mysqli_error($con);
}
```

And the tough part begins. I have linked the tables patient ID(primarykey) with diagnosis table, diagnosis_id(foreign key). What I want now is:

1. In patients profile I have a button that will send me to other page to add their diagnosis, but I need this page to include the ID or FirstName of this patient, so the diagnosis will be added to his profile. If this cannot be done, then; in diagnosis page from a dropdown I need to select the patient name where all the diagnosis infos will go (here, patients name will have the primary key, right?)
2. Since the patient will have more than one diagnosis, in patients profile I need to list all the diagnosis i have previously added for this patient.

Patients table in database contains:

```
id, datetime, patientname, birthdate, phonenumber, addres, city
```

Diagnosis table in database contains:

```
id, datetime, diagnosis, therapy, price, payment, notes, diagnosis_id
```

I was wondering what terms to google for these kind of database relationships?
 Someone has a line of code that would give me a hint? For the second, I found out I need to work with JOINTS right?

Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first question. But for 2nd one you will need to use JOIN statements, yes. You can check them out [on w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is very simple.

Add a field in the diagnosis table called `pid` or `patient_id` and put the `id` of the user in that field.

That `id` will be what associates both the patient and the diagnosis.

You will then need to write a query that fetches all diagnosis of a patient by their `id`.

I hope this explanation points you in the right direction.